# Another way to say " Having received no response"

Tags: questions

Please suggest other ways to phrase" Having received no response."

Comment: What does this question have to do with phrasing or answering questions?

Answer (score 1):

*Since I haven't heard back from ...*

Answer (score -1):

Since *we* did not hear from you...